# Magento Coupon.phtml does not work

Tags: php, magento

The `coupon.phtml` was removed from Magento files. I downloaded it from GitHub:

[Coupon.phtml](https://github.com/nandroid/MagentoFoundation/blob/master/app/magento-foundation/default/template/checkout/cart/coupon.phtml)

Then I modified `cart.phtml` as below:

```
<th class="a-center" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">
  <span class="nobr">
    <?php echo $this->__('Coupon') ?>
  </span>
</th>
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will notice that the files is same that removed and why you need modify cart.phtml?. i prefer that download magento files with right version and then copy/paste the removed files